# Posts inserted with wp_insert_posts aren't showing up in admin

Tags: ajax, wordpress, custom-post-type, multisite, wpml

I have a particular issue with inserting custom posts with `wp_insert_posts`.

**Circumstances:**

- WPML
- Multisite enabled
- Custom post type with name `order`
- Post creation triggered through Ajax from frontend
- The post is inserted in the original language, no translations

**What have I tried so far**

- Checked the post type register code to see if it contains any incompatible settings, tried all combinations -> noting. This is what is the closest thing to my problem: [wp_insert_post entries not showing in admin content list](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/wp_insert_post-entries-not-showing-in-admin-content-list/)

  - The resolution there is not applicable to me, as I execute it through Ajax, and WP is already initialized at the Ajax hook
- Went through WPML forums with all their posts related to similar issues, tried the steps provided there (although most of them talk about adding translations)
- Tried various other solutions

**Post insert code:**

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post([
        "post_type" => "order",
        "post_content" => "",
        "post_title" => $order->Name() . '&lt;' . $order->Email() . '&gt;',
        "post_status" => "publish",
        "post_author" => 1
    ]);

    update_post_meta($post_id, 'order_details', '{"some":"json here"}');
```

The post gets inserted in the table, and the listing page in admin shows it in the total counts, but the post doesn't show up in the list itself.

[image: Empty list]

**Post type register code**

```
if ( ! function_exists('ls_so_order') ) {

// Register Custom Post Type
function ls_so_order() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Orders', 'Post Type General Name', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Order', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Orders', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'ProductOrder', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Order Archives', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Order Attributes', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Order:', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Orders', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Order', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Order', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Order', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Order', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Order', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Orders', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Order', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into order', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this order', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Orders list', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Orders list navigation', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter orders list', 'ls-simple-order' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Order', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Simple Order Orders', 'ls-simple-order' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 20,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-cart',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => false,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'exclude_from_search'   => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => false,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'order', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'ls_so_order', 0 );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going back and forth in every forum I could find, and tinkering with @miguelcalderons answer, I found the culprit, and it is a very simple, although quiet hidden thing.

**[WordPress Reserved Terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms)**

WordPress has a quiet long list of reserved terms, and `order` being one of them.

After **replacing the custom post type slug with a different string**, it started working immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing this?

```
    $post_data = array(
        'post_title' => 'Test regex',
        'post_content' =>  $order->Name() . '&lt;' . $order->Email() . '&gt;',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1, 
);

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'order_details', '{"some":"json here"}');
```

Comment: That doesn't help. I have PHP 7, so I can specify an array directly with brackets. Also, didn't help. However, by tinkering with the settings, I got the solution. "order" is a reserved word in WordPress.